# parallax plug in not showing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, parallax.js

Parallax plugin is not working in my html file. Please help me to fix the bug.

I have created a HTML document where I have used parallax image effect in a div. 
https://github.com/munadilfahad/exam-19022017/blob/master/profile.html

image file is located in images folder
https://github.com/munadilfahad/exam-19022017/tree/master/images

css files are located in css folder
github.com/munadilfahad/exam-19022017/tree/master/css

and js files are located in js folder
github.com/munadilfahad/exam-19022017/tree/master/js

## div

div where I have used parallax plugin is,

```
<div class="parallax-window parallax-mirror" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/image.jpg"></div>
```

## JavaScript

I have linked below parallax js file the the bottom of the body tag,

```
<script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
```

## CSS

In my own css file (css/style.css), if have put below lines,

```
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}

.parallax-mirror {
    z-index:1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is with your HTML DOCTYPE, add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

instead of

```
<html>
```

and remove

```
$('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: 'images/image.jpg'});
```

from profile.js as you can use only one way to initiate parallax either from data-* attributes or using script.

Comment: adding <!DOCTYPE html> solves the problem. Great brother Vilas Kumar. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MunadilFahad If given solution solves your problem, then you can accept the solution and upvote would be appriciated ;)

Comment: I have first time posted question in this platform. I am not finding option to mark it solved and upvote.

Comment: @MunadilFahad this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers